# Create Backup of Attached SQL Server Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Good day!

I'm trying to create a standalone C# project with a SQL Server database attached so I only need to install a SQL Server Compact Edition.
I managed to connect to the said database and do some basic display, add and delete.

[image]

What I'm trying to do now is to have an option for the users to backup and restore the database.

Upon checking the files of the project, the tables and stored procs are in script format. Is it possible for it to be backed-up the same as how .mdf database files are backed-up and restored?

[image]

I am also open to suggestions on ways on how to easily have a standalone project be developed. So far this is only what I got. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: SSDT projects can and should be source controlled like any project. That would be your "backup". While the project may contain scripts to seed/generate data, the project is not a database, it just defines a database.

Comment: @Crowcoder, thanks for your time responding to my question. Does this mean that my approach to developing a standalone project is wrong?

Comment: I guess I need more clarification on what "standalone" means to you. SSDT projects are, in my opinion, a great way to go.

Comment: What I need to develop is a project in which the database is attached to the project when deployed without also needing to install the whole SQL Server package. This is for a single-user only. It must also support the backup and restore of the database. Can you help me with this?

Comment: SSDT could be part of a solution that allows you to embed a database into an application but it is not the whole solution unless you expect users to run Visual Studio. Just like you don't give users c# source code, you won't give them sql source either. You need to pull your entire solution into a deployment package and that is not something I can explain in an SO comment.

Comment: @Crowcoder, I understand. Thank you for the clarifications.